# Text DateStyle with short month name in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following outputs the complete month name, e.g. `July 11, 2022`

```
  Text("\(Date().now, style: .date)") // output: July 11, 2022
```

Is there a way to make it show just the short month name, e.g. `Jul 11, 2022` or `06/11/22`?

Comment: you have to use date formatter.

Comment: It's what I thought. It would be nice if we could change the format right in the `Text` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show current date without time in a short format.

```
 //Jul 11, 2022
 Text(Date().formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))

 //7/11/2022
 Text(Date().formatted(date: .numeric, time: .omitted))
```

**[formatted(date:time:) (Apple Developer Documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/3766588-formatted)**

- Generates a locale-aware string representation of a date using specified date and time format styles.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know they added the `formatted()` method to the `Date` class in `iOS15`, that's great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

#### SwiftUI 3+

We have now explicit initializer for that, like

```
Text(Date.now, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))
```

Comment: Ahh, a more `SwiftUI` oriented way, cool. Thanks a lot.